# Can we push the digital crown using the Apple Watch 2.0 Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch

Simple question: using watchOS 2, and its simulator in Xcode 7, is it possible to simulate pressing the Digital Crown? We can scroll it using the track pad, but I’ve not yet found a way to press it.

Can it be done? For instance, can we see the apps screen on the watch simulator yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cmd+Shift+H sends the same event to the simulated runtime as pressing the crown on the device.

Comment: Also it's possible to simulate turning the crown by scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Getting to the Home Screen on the  Watch just requires going to the "Home" option in the menu under Hardware (or Cmd+Shift+H), but I'm not sure that this simulates a Digital Crown press all-around. Might be worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd+Shift+B` sends the same event of button press